# How to find all the methods(static & non-static both) that are called inside a method in a class?

Tags: java

Given that-

```
public class Demo{ 
  public void Find(){ 
    Example.A(); 
    String str = new Example().B(); 
  } 
}
```

I want to find out the name of all the methods that are called inside the `Find()` method in the `Demo` class and store it in an `ArrayList` (Method `A()` and Method `B()` in this case). How do I achieve that?

`Example` is another class in the same package with two methods: A static method `A()` and non-static method `B()` which returns a `String`.

Comment: I haven't done anything like that, but I guess you need to go through the bytecode to do something like this.

Comment: oh i see. I didnt know about the javassist API. Used it and nw its working lik a charm. Thanks guys !